# Two women riddle

Tags: situation, family

Two women were walking together down the street, each carrying a baby in her arms, they seen approaching two men also walking together in the opposite direction to them, one of the women said to the other:

Look out, there are our fathers, fathers of our children, husbands of our mothers, and our own husbands.

Which **relationship** or **kinship** unites them?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eYlJH81dSiw

Comment: This is possibly plagiarism. I found this question on page 170 of Classic Logic Puzzles, by J.J Mendora Fernandez, George J. Summers, and Norman D. Willis,  copyright 2003. It's not word-for-word, but it's the same puzzle.

Comment: @Mithrandir Do you have a free location where that could be verified?

Comment: @Emrakul No, but I have the book...

Comment: @Emrakul   http://i.stack.imgur.com/HSeX2.png

Comment: @Mithrandir I actually laughed, not kidding. That's amazing. Lemme think a minute, and see if I can find a closer-to-verbatim source.

Comment: @Mithrandir I can't seem to find another source online, which is unusual. It suggests, though, that this puzzle is a fairly common one that gets often repeated, so I'm not sure there's much that can be done. For OP, though: in the future, please avoid copying puzzles, even reworded, from other sources, where possible. Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This question really puzzled me so I want to come up with some simple scenario:

> Imagine 2 girls who know each other or they are friends and they look at their fathers.

Which covers:
Here are our fathers + husbands of our mothers

> They grow older and their mothers die or disappear for some reason. So each of the girls stays with their father as kind of a half widow/orphan (the one with only one parent left).

Next

> Each of the girls marry the other girl's father.

This covers:

> there are our fathers + husbands of our mothers + our own husbands
>   *(husbands of our mothers: each girl is also the other girl's new mother)*

Now

> they all have children.

This now covers

> there are our fathers + fathers of our children + husbands of our mothers + and our own husbands

Comment: congrats! you have guessed than the mothers of the two women are dead good job @Avigrail

Answer (score 5):

> M1 is the father of W1, M2 is the father of W2.
>  M1 married W2 and M2 married W1, both couples had children.
>
>  The men are now our fathers, fathers of our children, husbands of our (step)mothers and our own husbands.

Comment: you are near the answer... but how it's possible than the mens are husbands of mothers of womans and husbands of them? ;)

Comment: he has explained that : M1 is huband of mother of W1 and husband of W2 too.

Answer (score 1):

> The men are son and father, the women are mother/daughter.

our fathers

> their fathers - son/father

fathers of our children

> the mother and daughter are holding the twins of the daughter

husbands of our mothers

> father/son

and our own husbands.

> the father is the husband of the woman

Answer (score 0):

> there are our fathers, fathers of our children, husbands of our mothers, and our own husbands.

- > There are our fathers, husbands of our mothers: woman1 is daughter of man1 and woman2 is daughter of man2.
- > There are our own husbands: woman1 married man2 and woman2 married man1.
- > There are fathers of our children: woman1 carried child of herself and man2 and woman2 carried child of herself and man1.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Puzzling SE! In the future, please remember to use the spoiler formatting to prevent accidental showing of the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

> Woman 1 and man 1 are married, and their child is baby 1.
> Woman 2 and man 2 are married and their child is baby 2.

No other relationships are needed.

> When one of the women said "Look out, there are our fathers, fathers of our children, husbands of our mothers, and our own husbands", she was speaking for the group consisting of herself, the other woman, and the two babies.

Our fathers

> The two men are the two babies' fathers.

Fathers of our children

> The two men are the fathers of the babies who are the children of the two women.

Husbands of our mothers

> The two men are the husbands of the mothers of the babies.

Our own husbands

> The two men are the women's husbands .